# i keep getting Uncaught ReferenceError: dropMenu is not defined and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to make nav bar with sub menus but i keeping getting dropMenu is not defined and when i hover over the two paris links i get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null any idea what is causing this 
here is my code 
html

```
<html>
<link type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet" href="vacation.css"/>
<head>
<title>Paris</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menus">
<div id ="parismenu">
<a href="#" onmouseover="dropMenu('dropmenu1')">Paris</a>
<div id="dropmenu1" class="dropmenus">
<a href="#">apple</a>
</div>
</div>
<div id ="disneymenu">
<a href="#" onmouseover="dropMenu('dropmenu2')">Paris</a>
<div id="dropmenu2" class="dropmenus">
<a href="#">apple</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="vacation.js"></script>
  </html>
```

css

```
div#menus{
margin-left:16px;
 }
 div#menus> div{
 float:left;
 margin:0px 20px;
 }
 div.dropmenus{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
 width:120px;
 background:teal;
 z-index:2;
 padding:4px;
 border: blue 3px solid;
 border-top:none;
 border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
 }
 div.dropmenus>a{
 display:block;
 margin:4px;
 padding:7px;
 font-size:14px;
 text-decoration:none;
 background:blue;
 border-radius:3px;
 color:red;
 }
 div#dropmenu1{
 left:24px;
 }
 div#dropmenu2{
 left:116px;
 }
```

javascript

```
 var fade=function(){
 return{
 init:function(id,flag,target){
 this.elem=document.ElementById(id);
 clearInterval(this.elem.si);
 this.target=target ? target : flag ? 100 : 0;
 this.flag = flag||1;
 this.alpha = this.elem.stle.opacity ? parseFloat(this.elem.style.opacity) * 100 : 0;
 this.elem.si=setIntterval(function(){fade.fadep()},20);
 },
 fadep:function(){
 if(this.alpha==this.target){
 clearInterval(this.elem.si);
 }
 else{
 var value=Math.round(this.alpha + ((this.target - this.alpha) * .05)) +(-1 * this.flag);
 this.elem.style.opacity=value/100;
 this.elem.style.filter='alpha(opacity=' + value + ')';
 this.alpha=value
 }}}}();

 var menu= ["dropmenu1","dropmenu2","dropmenu3"];
 function dropMenu(x){
 for(var m in menu){
 if(menu[m] != x){
 document.getElementById(menu[m]).style.display="none";
 }}
 if(document.getElementById(x).style.diplay=="block"){
 fade.init(x,1);
  }
 else{
 fade.init(x,0)}}
```

Comment: Its probably because your script tags are after the closing body tag. Try putting them right before it

Comment: i only get the style of null error now

Comment: where is element with id dropmenu3 or above code was just a sample?

Comment: that was a sample i only have 2 drop menus

Comment: Thats because your getElementById is missing the hash tag for the id. You probably need document.getElementById('#'+menu[m]).style.display="none";

Comment: i still get style of null after adding the #

Comment: i was wrong you dont need the # thats a jquery thing. Working through it ill through up a jsfiddle with just vanilla code when i get it

Comment: Where did you get this fader function? its full of spelling errors, also i have it so its not throwing any errors its just not fading the element in...

Comment: i was looking up tutorials on how to make a fade a effect without jquery here is the tutorial - http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/01/javascript-fade-in-out/

Comment: I have added another answer that is just vanilla js.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just use the jquery fader? I have cleaned up your javascript and html a little bit. Instead of using the element onMouseover event Im adding a listener to that element for that event after the document is loaded.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="menus">
    <div id="parismenu">
        <a href="#" class="dropmenu" data-menu-id="#dropmenu1">Paris</a>
        <div id="dropmenu1" class="dropmenus">
            <a href="#">apple</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="disneymenu">
        <a href="#" class="dropmenu" data-menu-id="#dropmenu2">Disney</a>
        <div id="dropmenu2" class="dropmenus">
            <a href="#">apple</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $('.dropmenu').on('mouseover', function (event) {
        $($(this).attr('data-menu-id')).fadeIn();
    });
    $('.dropmenu').on('mouseout', function (event) {
        $($(this).attr('data-menu-id')).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Then Your CSS is unchanged.

Heres a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gpHv6/1/) showing a working example.

Comment: i wanted to do vanilla javascript thanks for the help but if where to do it how im doing it what is causing the style of null error or is there a better way using only vanilla javascript

Answer (score 0):

Your array contains three ids and your html only has the first two - so

```
document.getElementById(menu[m])
```

will be undefined if m === 2

So you need to remove "dropmenu3" from the menu array.

Also, this line:

```
this.elem=document.ElementById(id);
```

should probably be

```
this.elem=document.getElementById(id);
```

Comment: next time you should set up a fiddle for this - you have lots of errors in the fade function you pasted; I think I fixed them all - see http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/RY8WZ/ (note that I've only bound the second link, and I used some jQuery, but you should be able to take it from there)

Comment: you should also learn how to use your browser's debugger to see where your error is happening - maybe have a look at https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: thats how i know the error should i have added where its happening as well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without jquery heres the code you will need. There were several typos in your original javascript. I also changed if so that all elements not being hovered were instantly hidden.

HTML

```
<div id="menus">
    <div id="parismenu">
        <a href="#" onmouseover="dropMenu('dropmenu1');">Paris</a>
        <div id="dropmenu1" class="dropmenus">
            <a href="#">apple</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="disneymenu">
        <a href="#" onmouseover="dropMenu('dropmenu2');">Paris</a>
        <div id="dropmenu2" class="dropmenus">
            <a href="#">apple</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var menu = ["dropmenu1", "dropmenu2"];

function dropMenu(x) {
    for (var m in menu) {
        if(menu[m] != x){
            document.getElementById(menu[m]).style.opacity = 0;
            document.getElementById(menu[m]).style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=0)';
        }
    }
    fade.init(x, 1);
}
var fade=function(){
    return{
        init:function(id, flag, target){
            this.elem = document.getElementById(id);
            clearInterval(this.elem.si);
            this.target = target ? target : flag ? 100 : 0;
            this.flag = flag || -1;
            this.alpha = this.elem.style.opacity ? parseFloat(this.elem.style.opacity) * 100 : 0;
            this.elem.si = setInterval(function(){fade.tween()}, 20);
        },
        tween:function(){
            if(this.alpha == this.target){
                clearInterval(this.elem.si);
            }else{
                var value = Math.round(this.alpha + ((this.target - this.alpha) * .05)) + (1 * this.flag);
                this.elem.style.opacity = value / 100;
                this.elem.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value + ')';
                this.alpha = value
            }
        }
    }
}();
```

I left your CSS unchanged. For a working jsfiddle check this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/XfyKZ/

Comment: thanks now could i just add the onmouseover where fade.init(X,1) is

Comment: calling the function from the onmouseover hides the open menus if you dont want to hide them then you can replace that with fade.init('dropmenu1',1)

Comment: could i just call onmouseout to have the menus not appear when your not hovering over paris

Comment: yeah thats fine for all the menus you could add onmouseout="fade.init('dropmenu1',0)"

Comment: Np, if either of my answers where correct if you could mark them as accepted it would be appreciated.